# how to get oracle stored procedure standard output in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to get the stand output in c# returned from oracle stored procedure. dbms_output.put_line('Hello Word')
The c# code i am using is

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = My_connection_string;               
    con.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("tmp_test", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.BindByName = true;
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

The oracle stored procedure code is

```
create or replace procedure tmp_test as
v_count integer;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Hello Word');
end;
```

The stored procedure execute successfully but I can't get the Hello Word back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some struggle i have managed to find the answer and decided to post that might help other.

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = My_connection_string;               
    con.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("tmp_test", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.BindByName = true;
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    //it is included dbms_output
    cmd.CommandText = "begin dbms_output.enable (1000); end;";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    string out_string;
    int status = 0;
    cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE (:out_string, :status); END;";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("out_string", OracleType.VarChar, 32000);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("status", OracleType.Double);
    cmd.Parameters[0].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters[1].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    out_string = cmd.Parameters[0].Value.ToString();
    status = int.Parse(cmd.Parameters[1].Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a the documentation for DBMS_OUTPUT package in Oracle - [DBMS_OUTPUT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#CIHBFFDB)

It specifically states that it's used for debugging Oracle Stored Procedures and that this is in essence a debug buffer that you need to actively poll use GET_LINES in order to see the output.

Comment: Do i need to use GET_LINES in c# code. if yes how do i use this please.

Comment: You need to return the value from GET_LINES in your original stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Function in PL/SQL should be something like this:

```
create or replace function tmp_test as
begin
   RETURN 'Hello World';
end;
```